# Execute escaped Windows command from Node.js on WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The following command is executed successfully in the CMD shell on Windows:

```
CMD /S /C " "..\..\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "
```

If I try to execute the command from Node.js running inside the WSL, I get an error:

```
cp.spawn('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe', ['/S', '/C', '" "..\\..\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" "'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

The same holds true for the bash shell:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /S /C '" "..\..\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "'
```

I didn't found a way so far to apply the correct CMD escaping in Node.js or the bash shell.

Comment: You're trying to run a Windows executable in a *NIX environment. That doesn't depend on escaping but *the ability to run Windows executables*.

Comment: Executing Windows commands from Ubuntu inside the WSL is supported by Microsoft :), also it is a bit odd.

Comment: Have you tried `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'`

Comment: @Philippe This version works :), but it uses the odd CMD escaping rules which I cannot use for my application.

Comment: The code I gave uses much simpler CMD escaping rules than yours.

Comment: @Philippe I want to disable CMD parsing with the /S flag, the command should be executed as given https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by starting an interactive CMD session and executing the command via stdin. Nevertheless, a direct solution would be better.

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const process = cp.spawn('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe', [], {stdio: ['pipe','inherit', 'inherit']});

process.stdin.write('CMD /S /C " "..\\..\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" "\r\n');

process.kill();
```

Comment: Can you use this form : `const process = cp.spawn('C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', [], {});` ?